# How to automatically restart Next.js app after an update in another library?

Tags: javascript, next.js, monorepo, microbundle

I have a monorepo with two apps:

- The web app (Next.js)
- The UI library (Tailwind, which uses [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle))

The only way I managed to make the web app see the changes I make to the UI library is by:

- Making the changes
- Rebuild the UI library (in this case, I'm using `microbundle watch`)
- Manually restart the Next.js server

My question is: how can I automatically restart the Next.js server every time the files within `ui/dist` are recreated (because they are rebuilt every time a change is made)?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but you might be able to customise the webpack config https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to watch any files and restart a node app, the Next.js app in this instance, when they're modified.

First, create a `nodemon.json` file in the Next.js project folder with the following contents, replacing the path to your `ui/dist` folder accordingly.

```json
{   
    "ignore": ["node_modules", ".next"],
    "watch": ["path-to/ui/dist/**/*"],
    "ext": "js json",
    "exec": "next dev"
}
```

Then, you'll have to replace your `dev` script to run `nodemon` instead.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also this can be easily used with [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) if the OP wants to execute both `microbundle watch` and `nodemon` in a single command. (A `dev` script for concurrently needs to be added in the __base__ package.json of the monorepo then.)